# KnockoutJs - why is init binding handler is only getting called once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem whereby the init: function is not being called on the 2nd time the data is updated from the server.

Is there any reason why this might happen?

I'm using the mapping plugin.  Another issue I don't understand is do I need to call the mapping plugin function differently depending on whether this is the 1st call or 2nd call?

**JS**

```
 function ViewMemberPopup(memberId) {

        $.get("/People/GetMemberDetails?memberId=" + memberId, function (data) {            
            viewMemberModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);            
            ko.applyBindings(viewMemberModel.model, $("#memberDetailsContainer")[0]);
        });
    }


 // binding handler
 ko.bindingHandlers.renderMemberModal = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            $(element).modal("show");            
        }
    };
```

**HTML:**
I've used renderMemberModal:true for the binding handler, not sure why I need a property attached to it. I just need to call the render function...

```
     <div class="modal fade" id="viewMemberModal" data-bind="renderMemberModal: true" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
            <h3>
                Member Details</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <div data-bind="template: { name: 'memberDetailsTemplate' }">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btnx closeModal">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using bootstrap css to show the modal pop-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would usually not want to keep calling applyBindings on the same element on each update.  This can end up adding multiple event handlers depending on the bindings that you use.  If you were to do that, then you would want to at least call `ko.cleanNode` on the element.  Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/F4AzB/

Rather than call applyBindings on each update, I think that it is easier to let the `template` binding (or control-flow bindings that are wrappers to the template binding) handle updating the content.

Your viewModel could have an observable to represent your data.  Then, you could update that observable with new copies of your data.

In that case, what you would really want to do is have your custom binding just have an update function and be sure to access the main observable, so that it fires every time you call your update function.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.custom = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());  //just for subscription
        console.log("hit");
    }  
};
```

Would look something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/dNsW8/

Comment: Just trying to go through and understand the sample. ko.mapping.fromJS(dataFromServer, null, viewModel.myData()) - why 3 params, I thought it only took 2? Is there any docs on this?

Comment: ko.mapping.fromJS can take three parameters.  The first is the data, the second is mapping options, and the third is the object that you want to update.  If you are dealing with an already mapped object that you want to update, then you can pass it as the second parameter, as it does not need the mapping options again and will recognize that you passed an already mapped object and not mapping options.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in jsFiddle?  What version of KO are you using?  Try it with 1.3 beta (or current build from github), $data is available everywhere and not just in jQuery templates.

Comment: I've tried to do my best but its just not my day I'm afraid, not even jquery ui is working in fiddle after swapping from bootstrap. http://jsfiddle.net/dNsW8/3/

Comment: Thanks, that helped me out a lot. I've now got a working solution!

Answer (score 1):

On the Knockoutjs site http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html discusses custom bindings.

*Knockout will call your init function once for each DOM element that you use the binding on. There are two main uses for init:
- To set any initial state for the DOM element
- To register any event handlers so that, for example, when the user clicks on or modifies the DOM element, you can change the state of the associated observable*

So by design, the Init is only called once to setup the binding.  It's purpose to configure the DOM object so that the Update method works correct.